# How to insert link in notification using C#?

Tags: c#

I am developing an application to watch file changes in folder and display notification to users.This function is OK.But I have a difficult to insert link(file directory) in notification.As this link is need to open watched folder.

Can anyone suggest how this could be implemented?

code:

```
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    this.notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1, "File " + e.ChangeType, e.FullPath, ToolTipIcon.Info);            
}
private void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    this.notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1, "File Renamed", e.OldFullPath + " renamed to " + e.FullPath, ToolTipIcon.Info);
}
```

I would like to display file directory of [e.FullPath] as link in notification(except e.Name).
    eg. e.FullPath -> C:\TEMP\test.txt, e.Name -> test.txt
I want to display [C:\TEMP] as link.

**Thanks all for suggesting.That difficult is OK now.If click notification, open watched folder.**

**My code:**

```
this.notifyIcon1.BalloonTipClicked += new System.EventHandler(this.linkLabel_LinkClick);

private void linkLabel_LinkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(C:\TEMP\test.txt);            
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you have implemented so far.

Comment: Please clarify what "insert link(file directory) in notification" means?

Comment: @TMB This is window application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to let the user click a link in the notification that opens the path in Explorer, here's one way to do it.

1. Add a LinkLabel to the notification window.
2. Create a LinkLabel.Link object in the code behind that stores the desired path.
3. Set up a handler for the LinkLabel's LinkClicked event and make a call to open Explorer to the path in the Link.

```cs
// step 2 -- implement where you have access to the desired path
linkLabel1.Links.Add(new LinkLabel.Link(0, 0, "C:\\"));

// step 3 -- open the path in Explorer
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Link.LinkData.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MessageBox` for notifications, then you need to implement your own form and put whatever you need on it, like `LinkLabel` as Jake suggested.

And the desired location can be opened by putting the following code into `LinkClicked` eventhandler (assuming the text of your link is the location you want to open):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(linkLabel1.Text);
```